# Limit number of results for Songkick API

Tags: json, api, songkick

I'm trying to limit the number of results that this pulls:

```
http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/venues.json?query={venue term}&apikey={API KEY}
```

I've tried adding on `maxResults`, `limit`, `results`.. none of them seem to work.

I can't find anything in the documentation. Anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for venue search](https://www.songkick.com/developer/venue-search) mentions the `per_page` argument, that limits how many items are returned for each request.

You can try using:

`http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/venues.json?query={venue term}&per_page=10&apikey={API KEY}`

It accepts any value between 1 and 50.